# IBM i Access doesn't start on Fedora

Tags: java, fedora, ibm-midrange

Here is my setup:
System76 Gallago Pro
Fedora 30
OpenJDK 1.8.0_201 (I did try Oracle as well)

I installed per IBM's instructions, using the installer script from the command line. I went through the installer menu and got to the success screen. I have done this a half dozen times on other machines and with OS upgrades on this same machine.

When I use the super key to find the program it is there; I click on the icon and my box returns to the desktop - but i Access doesn't start.
If I start via the command line using the start script, I get `MSGGEN045 - A graphical user interface is not available.`

If I run the java program directly
`java -Xmx1024m -jar /opt/ibm/iAccessClientSolutions/acsbundle.jar` I get the same message as when using the start script.

How can I get past this error? Or,what else can I do to track down what is happening?

Comment: I highly recommend subscribing to the [midrange.com mailing lists](https://lists.midrange.com/). The most knowledgeable people are there, and that venue is not restricted to the topics and question-answer format that Stack Overflow is. The most appropriate list for this particular question is probably the [main one](https://lists.midrange.com/mailman/listinfo/midrange-l).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have anything Fedora specific but it seems that you either didn't install a Java Runtime Environment or just a headless version of it (jre-headless). Install a full JRE and everything should be fine.

You could check this with yum:

yum list installed | grep jre

Comment: The command you gave returns nothing. However, `java -version` returns (in part)`OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_201-b09)`

Comment: Currently, `sudo dnf install 'java-1.8.0-openjdk'` is the fix. The version will change in the future.

Answer (score 2):

I've had two issues when running iACS on Fedora.  The first was the OS had a headless JVM installed by default.  The second was something to do with sound.

Based on "MSGGEN045 - A graphical user interface is not available", I'd suspect a headless JVM.

HTH

Edit:
I checked for the headless JVM at the direction of IBM support.  I don't remember the exact wording, but the name of the installed package was a dead giveaway.  A simple "rpm -qa" was all it took.

Comment: How do I determine if my JRE is headless? Can you edit your answer to include the info? It may help others

Answer (score 0):

Fedora is running wayland and not X11. Java doesn't play nice with wayland as of yet. As far as I know there are no plans yet to fix that. This is a good place to start https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=1b366edf-0e70-40d5-8d92-30d401edd97a

Comment: I have seen this as the possible issue in other places. So, I tried restarting and logged in under xorg. I get the same results as under Wayland